# Software Fault Tolerance

Tags: fault, fault-tolerance

Does anyone know how software fault tolerance is implemented in Air Traffic Control Systems?

Some URLs would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lockheed published some articles about this a while back. Take a look **[here](http://pompone.cs.ucsb.edu/~msa/reading/cristian-airtraffic.pdf)**.

Many systems use Ada, which explicitly supports verification of propositions and other formal-logic ideas so that you can guarantee system consistency. Read more about that **[here](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2009/IMECS2009_pp1095-1099.pdf)**.

You will also want to search for ERAM, the acronym for "**[En Route Automation Modernization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERAM)**", which is the name of the new system that's (very) slowly being rolled out now in the US. This is the replacement for the En Route Host System, the existing legacy system that keeps everything from crashing into each other.

Answer (score 0):

The [software fault tolerance](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/SoftwareFaultTolerance.htm) link here covers:

- Timeouts
- Audits
- Exception handling
- Rollbacks
- Incremental rebooting
- Voting